# Can I getParcelableExtra by lazy (delegate)

Tags: android, kotlin

I just want to make sure, can I getParcelableExtra by lazy (delegate) in kotlin?

I have tried to do it, but I got some error, is there any other way?

model class :

```kotlin
@Parcelize
data class Branch(
    val branch_code: String,
    val branch_name: String,
    val total_warehouse: Int,
    val id: Int
): Parcelable
```

activity A class :

```kotlin
BranchAdapter(binding.etSearch, {
    openActivity<OverViewActivity> {
        putExtra(ParseExtra.OBJECT, it)
    }
})
```

activity B class :

```kotlin
private val dataBranch : Branch by lazy {
   intent.getParcelableExtra(ParseExtra.OBJECT)!!
}
```

### ERROR

```
..\OverViewActivity.kt: (49, 40): Type inference failed. Please try to specify type arguments explicitly.
..\OverViewActivity.kt: (49, 45): Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> ??? but () -> Branch was expected
..\OverViewActivity.kt: (50, 16): Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun <T : Parcelable!> getParcelableExtra(p0: String!): T!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an extension for Activity to get the parcelable extra

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Activity.getParcelableExtra(key: String) =
    lazy { intent.getParcelableExtra<T>(key) }
```

and then use it like

```kotlin
private val dataBranch: Branch by getParcelableExtra(ParseExtra.OBJECT)
```

or

```kotlin
private val dataBranch by getParcelableExtra<Branch>(ParseExtra.OBJECT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must specify type arguments explicitly. Try this way:

```
private val dataBranch : Branch by lazy {
   intent.getParcelableExtra<Branch>(ParseExtra.OBJECT)!!
}
```